# what is xargs rm -f in node pre install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, frontend

I am facing an issue in building our code on a windows machine, this seems to be working fine in mac book, can anyone help me to understand what this line does in code building, and is there any windows alternative to this?

```
"preinstall": "find ./node_modules -maxdepth 1 -type l | xargs rm -f"
```

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/

Comment: it removes symlinks from `./node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./node_modules -maxdepth 1 -type l
```

Runs the `find` command to search starting from the path specified for the specified things.  The arguments tell you where and what it is looking for:

- `./node_modules`:  look under the directory `./node_modules`
- `-maxdepth 1`: limit the search to a depth of 1 (so only looks in `node_modules` and not any subdirectories)
- `-type l`: look for files of type `l` (symlinks)

this will print out all the matching files -- all the symlinks in `./node_modules` and that list is the piped to the `xargs` command:

```
xargs rm -f
```

which runs the command `rm -f` with each input (file from the find command) as an additional argument.

So overall, this just removes all symlinks in the directory `./node_modules`.  However, since it doesn't quote anything, it will misbehave if you have any filename containing spaces.

Comment: Thanks Chris, is there any way I can run it in my windows machine , at present it gives error on xargs as it's not in my machine

Comment: Any Idea on this error, when runing this command?? > find ./node_modules -maxdepth 1 -type 'l' | xargs rm -f

FIND: Parameter format not correct

Comment: @AshishMishra: probably mean you're running the wrong 'find' command -- I think Windows has some non-standard version by default.